# How to load a document in background?

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to write a Firefox extension that speeds up browsing page sequences by preloading sequence items, preprocessing them, and showing on request.

Is there any way to load and process DOM of arbitrary web page (on the same site as currently opened) in background from privileged extension code?

Ideally, the document's javascript should work as it would in a normal browser window. I suspect a hidden window would be required for this. The context on that javascript should not be privileged then.
Loading should allow user to continue normal browsing in all visible browser windows.

I don't like the idea of injecting iframes to currently opened document and making them optionally visible (the principle used by [Webcomic reader userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/59842))

Answer (score 2):

From the add-on SDK, the [`page-worker`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/packages/addon-kit/page-worker.html) module might be close to what you need:

> The page-worker module provides a way to create a permanent, invisible
>   page and access its DOM.

That said, I have no idea whether it's possible to load that invisible page into a (current or new) tab / window. You *might* be able to replace a current tab's `document.body` by the page-worker's one. Possibly. If it's legal.

Comment: Checked out SDK. Seems to be an overkill for my small extension. Moreover page-worker relies on HiddenFrame, which in turn, creates iframes in hidden window global static object.

Comment: So far, I can't make iframe load the target probably due to messed up namespaces or access rights. Still trying.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a lightweight browser extension to collect all links on a page onload and use link tags to prefetch the content for each, the browser will load those pages in the background: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Link_prefetching_FAQ

OR

If you need to preload a page and have access to its DOM from extension land, you could use the Page Worker API from the Add-on SDK: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-worker.html

Comment: I like this idea. Unfortunately it provides no DOM access.

Comment: @Basilevs - please see the edit I made to my answer above! :)

Comment: That's exactly what Slanec proposes.

Answer (score -1):

I believe so.  assuming your javascript is already running

```
var doc = gBrowser.selectedBrowser.contentDocument;
```

will get your the document of the loaded tab, you can then process it and do with it what you want.  Doing it in the background and keeping the app responsive is a different story :)

Comment: -1 as returned object is 1. visible 2. foreground 3. has currently opened url (not an arbitrary one)

Comment: totally misread your Q originally, but what do you mean by visible?

Comment: I mean that the document returned is the one shown to user right now. Therefore, should I change it, user will be affected by the change. I want a way to load page without affecting user browsing.